# Структуры в Golang

Tags: golang, golang-struct

```
 type strData struct {
 rx int
 check1 int
}
func main() {
    str := new(strData)
str.rx = 3
flagWinD1 := winDiag1(str.rx, xo, check1)
```

Ошибка компилятора: .\testingModule.go:39:28: cannot use str.rx (type int) as type strData in argument to winDiag1

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Ошибку читали? Пишет что функция, вызывается с неверным аргументом.

Comment: Покажите полный пример, пожалуйста. Желательно на play.golang.org. Полагаю, что ошибок может быть сразу несколько и ответ на вопрос, пусть и правильный, только лишний раз запутает Вас.

Comment: Да вообщем то ошибки заключаются только в этом, они все одинаковые, ругаются именно то что переменная в структуре не может вывестись.

Comment: Функция `winDiag1` первым аргументом хочет получить структуру `strData`, а Вы передаёте ей `str.rx`, т.е. типа `int`. Об этом и сообщение об ошибке. Если перевести его на русский, то получиться что-то вроде "не могу использовать _str.rx_ (типа _int_) как тип _strData_ в аргументах _winDiag1_".

Comment: Причём переменная `str` у Вас создана с помощью оператора `new`, который возвращает указатель на переменную. Иными словами, переменная `str` типа `*strData`. если Вы передадите функции её так: `winDiag(*str, xo, check1)`, то конкретно эта ошибка будет решена. Но я боюсь, что всплывут новые.

Answer (score 2):

Все просто. Нужны большие буквы.

```
type strData struct {
 Rx     int
 Check1 int
}
```

Comment: Нет же. В данном коде доступ к полям есть. Но, судя по ошибке, функция ожидает первым параметром strData, а не int

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае все работает.
Вот ваш пример.
Здесь все ок.
https://play.golang.org/p/HxEHEFp--ke